# Does the for foreach construct in java create a hard or soft copy?

Tags: java, variables, foreach

Say I have the following piece of java code

```
ArrayList<Double> myList = new Double[100];
for (Double x : myList)
    x = randomDouble();
```

Does this actually modify myList or just the dummy variable?

I realize I should just try this code segment out, but I think this is the sort of thing I should be able to google or search for on this site, and several queries so far have turned up nothing useful.

Comment: I believe for an array it would modify but I expect that for ArrayList that Matthew Flaschen is correct.

Comment: An array wouldn't make it a reference either; as Matt said, Java doesn't have reference variables that work that way

Comment: Yes, you should really try that small code segment.

Comment: @James Black - you can check your belief against what the JLS says here:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't modify `myList`.  It works by calling [`myList.iterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#iterator%28%29), then (repeatedly) [`hasNext()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) and [`next()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29), none of which change `myList`.

Also, Java does not have C++-style references.  That means you don't need to worry (even without looking at the API) about `x` being a reference that could modify `myList`.

Finally, that's invalid syntax.  It should be:

```
ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
/* or new ArrayList<Double>(100), but that's only an optimization 
(initial capacity), not the size. */
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Does this actually modify myList or just the dummy variable?*

Just the dummy variable.

BTW you code doesn't even compile.

It should be either:

```
ArrayList<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>(100);
```

or

```
Double[] myList = new Double[100];
```

Answer (score 2):

So with the benefit of hindsight, the answer I was looking for would look something like this:

Using the "=" operator will set the object x to a new value without modifying any of the values in the variable myList.  To modify myList using the foreach loop construct, one needs to access a modifier method for the object.  For example:

```
for (MyDouble x : myList) {
    x.setX( randomDouble() );
}
```